# Magento related products

Tags: magento-1.8, soap

I'm trying to make a function that return all related product of a product, using the productId

So I make this in /var/www/website/api/catalog/get_collection.php :

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/Init.php';

$task = new Init(__FILE__);
        > try {
        > 
        >         $client = $task->getSOAPClient();
        >         $session = $task->getSOAPSession($client);
        > 
        >         $productId = $_GET['productId'];
        >         $productId = (string)$productId;
        >         $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product_link.list', array('type' => 'related', 'product' => $productId));  
        >         var_dump ($result);
              } 
        catch(Exception $e) {
        >     $task->errorResponse($e->getMessage()); 
              }
```

I call this "get_collection.php" file from my google chrome with this line :

`http://magento.dev.website.com/api/catalog/get_collection.php?productId=557`

And this is the result I get :

{
error: "Product not exists."
}

I try to replace $productId in the array of argument by the value of the productId, but still the same error.

Please, help me >.<
Oh, it's on Magento 1.8.0, if this can help someone helping me ^^

Comment: are you trying to extend Magento's API?

Comment: I just make this php file, if it's your question =)

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do. Normally, there is no file `app/Init.php`. Seems you want to use SOAP in order to get related products. This is described [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductLink/catalogProductLink.html).

Comment: I have seen it yesterday, and try 'var_dump($proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_link.list', array('related', 'Sku')));', but it doesn't work, and like it doesn't use the productId, I don't know how to use it. And I'm trying to make a function that return all related product of a product, using the productId (update my question to explain it)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use SOAP v2. As written in the comments, there is no file `App/Init.php`, so I have no idea what you are trying to do. The documentation of the SOAP API is rather good. [This page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductLink/catalog_product_link.list.html) explains how to get the related products. Something like this should work:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$result = $proxy->catalogProductLinkList($sessionId, 'related', $productId);
var_dump($result);
```

Make sure that you configure Magento correctly. You can have a look at this [Inchoo article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/) for a reference.

Comment: I try SOAP v2, but doesn't config', and don't have access to make it. But I also try again the '$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product_link.list', array('type' => 'related', 'product' => '1'));', and I have a new error "product not exists.". How can I had $productId in this line, which I have (using GET) ?

Comment: I edit my question, new start of solution =P

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to login in order to be able to use the SOAP API. You need the API credentials.

Comment: This is made by the Init.php file, correctly working for the get_product.php like that :
`require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/Init.php';
$task = new Init(__FILE__);

try {
    $client = $task->getSOAPClient();
    $session = $task->getSOAPSession($client);`

Comment: Okay. Then the product with the ID just does not exist in the store.

Comment: I have take an existing product, adding it related products, and take his Id to test the function. It exists, I saw it in the backend. I just saw that if I test for others products, I don't have the error, or any answer. It's seems it's the only product which the function accept Oo

Comment: Update : When I try the get_product on the same productId, function find the good one =/ (I also try using the sku of the product, but that doesn't help me)

Comment: This is not reproducable for us, so I think nobody will be able to help any further. Just two last hints: Try to hard-code the ID for testing purposes and try it as a string like `'557'`. You use the SOAP v1 function call. Are you sure you need to use v1? Maybe try with SOAP v2. Both versions are documented.

Comment: Yes, I have to use v1. I try hard-code, doesn't solve the problem. Thank's for your help =)